# Batch file move specific files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a very large number of files with this template:

```
example1.part001.rar
example1.part002.rar
example1.part003.rar
...

example2.part001.rar
example2.part002.rar
example2.part003.rar
...
```

and sometimes with only two digits after "part"

```
example3.part01.rar
example3.part02.rar
example3.part03.rar
...
```

I'm trying to create a batch file that first makes *n* directories (*n* is for number of groups of files) with the name " example *n* ", and then that moves all relatives file into them.
I will explain better.

I have

```
cat.part01.rar
cat.part02.rar
cat.part03.rar
dog.part001.rar
dog.part002.rar
mouse.part01.rar
mouse.part02.rar
mouse.part03.rar
mouse.part04.rar
```

I want to first make the directories "cat", "dog" and "mouse, and then move all relatives file into them (I mean all "foldername.part*.rar in "foldername"), so "cat.part*.rar" files into "cat" folder and so on.
Files are many, and filenames are very very different and random.

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: You suppose to create a script and ask for concrete problems you meet, not to ask somebody to do the whole work for you...

Comment: I assure you I have try with for, dir but I couldn't find a solution...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.rar) do (set $file=%%~na
                       set $file=!$file:^.= !
                       call:work %%a)
exit /b
:work
for %%b in (!$file!) do (if not exist %%b md %%b
                         copy "%1" ".\%%b"
                         exit /b)
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! I only had to replace "copy" with "move". Easy, tidy and short, this is the solution I was looking for! Thank you again

Comment: Can you put the Question as answered, please

Comment: Oh sorry, I have found a problem... many files have names like "abc.def.ghi.part01.rar", so delimiter "." can't be used... I have tried to put ".part" as delimiter, but it considers .,p,a,r,t separates and not as single word... how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: If you just can have one level more (aaa.bbb.ccc.rar)see the edit. But if you can have (aaa.bbb.ccc.dddd.rar) then it will not work.

Comment: New edit : Now you can have "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee.rar" it will work

Answer (score 1):

This should do it also, and handle filenames with `!` in them too.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.rar) do (
 if exist "%%a" for %%b in ("%%~na") do (
    md "%%~nb" 2>nul
    move "%%~nb.part*.rar" "%%~nb" >nul
 )
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I get a list of groups by splitting the file name by '.'.  I then get the uniq values of the first column.  For each of the results I create the directory.  Then move all files into the directory

```
#/usr/bin/sh

groupnames=(`ls *.rar | awk -F"." '{print $1}' | uniq`)

for i in ${groupnames[*]}; do

  mkdir $i
  mv $i.*.rar ./$i/

done
```

Comment: I think this is for Linux, I was looking for Windows... thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Example files of test:

ball.part1.rar
ball.part2.rar

cat.part01.rar
cat.part02.rar

dog.part001.rar
dog.part002.rar

The script creates folders **ball**, **cat**, **dog**, after that, it moves the files to their respective folders, works with part**X**, part**XY** and part**XYZ** in filename

```
@echo off
@break off
@title Batch file move specific files
@color 0a
@cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~1" NEQ "" (
  set "WORKINGDIR=%~1"
) else (
  set "WORKINGDIR=!CD!"
)

if not exist "!WORKINGDIR!\*.rar" (
  set "WORKINGDIR=!CD!"
)

if not exist "!WORKINGDIR!\*.rar" (
  echo There are no winrar files in this directory
  echo.
  echo Exiting...
  echo.
  ping -n 4 localhost>nul
  pause
  exit
)

for %%a in ( "!WORKINGDIR!\*.rar" ) do (
  set "name=%%~nxa"
  if "!name:~-4!" EQU ".rar" (
    set "name=!name:~0,-4!"
  )
  if "!name:~-8,5!" EQU ".part" (
    echo !name:~-7! | find ".">nul
    if "!errorlevel!" NEQ "0" (
      set "name=!name:~0,-8!"
    ) else (
      set "skip=yes"
    )
  ) else if "!name:~-7,5!" EQU ".part" (
    echo !name:~-6! | find ".">nul
    if "!errorlevel!" NEQ "0" (
      set "name=!name:~0,-7!"
    ) else (
      set "skip=yes"
    )
  ) else if "!name:~-6,5!" EQU ".part" (
    echo !name:~-5! | find ".">nul
    if "!errorlevel!" NEQ "0" (
      set "name=!name:~0,-6!"
    ) else (
      set "skip=yes"
    )
  )
  if not defined skip (
    set "skip=no"
  )
  if "!skip!" EQU "no" (
    if not exist "!WORKINGDIR!\!name!\" (
      mkdir "!WORKINGDIR!\!name!\"
    )
    move /y "!WORKINGDIR!\%%~nxa" "!WORKINGDIR!\!name!\%%~nxa"
  )
  set "skip=no"
)

pause
exit
```

Comment: It works, thank you!
The user sachadee have found a shorter solution, but the final result is the same. Maybe your code has something more, since it is longest?

Comment: Yes , exactly . I made a larger code to avoid possible bugs I imagined what might occur with certain filenames with dots in the beginning there is also a section for working with directories for argument , for example , you can call script.bat "Directory" is passed as parameter %~1 for script.bat , but if you call the script.bat directly, it uses the current directory to work, so you can put the script in the folder with the files and run well , there are also checking if there are files in WinRAR folder.

Comment: My biggest is because of these reasons , usually when post codes batch script , few programming so do the necessary checks , just make the code work, I always try to maintain compatibility and a higher degree of reliability in the code . It's like I say , it's not because the code works , you want to say that the code is right . Good programming practices , even in batch script is possible.